# How to set variable of a class from another function?

Tags: python

I want to replace 'YouTube' with 'Gmail' from fat function. This class and function are in two separate files.

```
class Data():
    url = 'YouTube'


from . import Data
def fat():
    r = 'Gmail'
    Data.url = r
    return "something"
```

how can i do this?

Comment: So... What's wrong with this code?

Comment: @Rawing when i am printing the url of class Data. then i am still getting 'YouTube'

Comment: How are you printing these url? Add some code please.

Comment: @H.G. where are you printing that ? Can you show complete code please ?

Comment: call function fat() before you print Data.url.

Answer (score 0):

Actually It's showing 'Youtube' because you are not calling fat() function i guess here is the code please go for it

file class_var contains

```
class Data():
    url = 'YouTube'
```

file func_var contains

```
from class_var import Data
def fat():
    r = 'Gmail'
    Data.url = r
    return "something"

fat()
print Data.url
```

In this criteria both files are in same directory.
Hope this will help you